# Best way to do the runtime UI changes on User Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, user-controls

I am new to the .net and I am working on the some functionality in office that is as below

**Jobs.aspx.cs**

```
protected void gvActionItems_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    //setting the value of the user control property 
}
```

**JobUserControl.ascx.cs**

```
public int _usrcontrolproperty
{
  get{return _usrcontrolproperty;}
  set{
    //depending on the value of the property fetch the data from the database and binding those data on the user controls FormView
    }
}

protected void fvJob_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Making the dynamic UI changes that is setting properties of controls  depending upon the values of binding data
}
```

This is how i did the required UI changes in databound event of form view, but one of senior says **'It's bad architectural code design it has extra memory issue and make the UI changes in the _usrcontrolproperty set method after the data bind.'**. So i want to know

```
1) Is this really bad architectural code ? If bad then why ?
2) And if my seniors way is bad then also Why ?
```

Because i thought the UI changes should done at the the time of the binding the data

Comment: Can he explain the "extra memory issue"?

Comment: @Simon i tried to reason with him but he doesn't tell me.That's why I asked here.

Comment: @Curiosity He/She is seems to have his/her own memory problems and for the design of coding part the way given by the **Simon** is far better than you are doing it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am with the @Simon on this one but I would have a RefreshData(value) method. Therefore, the calling code would be:

```
UserControl.RefreshData(value);
```

This gives the calling API the option of refreshing at that point or deferring the decision.
An in this method you can use as ,

```
 Public static RefreshData(<datatype>data)
 {
   //Assign the value to the property 
   //Get the data from database 
   //Bind the data 
 }
```

And you can also make your property private or protected if you don't want to expose the property to other classes.

Answer (score 1):

If your senior cannot backup his/her claims.. then he/she isn't really someone you should try learning from. I'm not sure what the "memory issue" is that he/she is referring to, however it's hard to tell with your stripped down code.

That being said, I would reconsider databinding in a property set purely because you open yourself up to "gotcha's" later down the track when people start setting this property.

Instead, I would have a `Refresh()` method. Therefore, the calling code would be:

```
UserControl.Property = value;
UserControl.RefreshData();
```

This gives the calling API the option of refreshing at that point or deferring the decision.

Comment: so the data binding should be done into the Refresh() method along with the UI changes

Comment: Fetching data and databinding should be done in refresh. I will update my answer to be clearer.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help and about the UI changes it should be done at the time of the data binding right ?